# Converting a function (as a string) to be graphed by TChart?

Tags: delphi

I am getting the user to input a function, e.g. y = 2x^2 + 3, as a string. What I am looking to do is to enter that string into TChart and for TChart to graph the function.

As far as I know, TChart/TeeChart will only accept X values that are assigned values, e.g. -10 to 10 for X, so the X value would need to be calculated each time - this isn't an issue.

The issue is getting each part of the inputted function and substituting the X-values into each part. The workaround I have found is to get the user to enter the degree for each part of the function, e.g. 2 for X^2, 3 for X^3, etc. but is there a cleaner way of doing this?

If I could convert the inputted string into a Mathematical formula which TeeChart would accept, that would be the ideal outcome.

Comment: Use an expression evaluator?  There's one in the JclExprEval unit in the freeware Jedi JCL library, available on Sourceforge.

Comment: I second what MartynA says. I use this code. It is excellent. It doesn't have a power operator though. I added one myself and submitted a feature request but it wasn't done I think.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to use external units :(

Comment: I cannot use external units or anything of that nature I am afraid!

Comment: Then what exactly is the question? The obvious answer here is that you need to learn how to do it, then write all that code. There is no built-in way to do what you want. You ask "but is there a cleaner way of doing this?" - Yes, there is, but you are apparently forbidden from using existing libraries. Writing mathematical evaluators, although not super-hard, is kinda like inventing the wheel all over again. It is still going to be round. Someone else has already done this work, lots of times, if you cannot use their code to fuel your program, **what is the question?**

Answer (score 3):

Saying that you can't use external units effectively makes your question unanswerable in the SO format, because the topic is far broader (and deeper) that can comfortably be dealt with in SO's Q&A format.  So the following is at best an outline:

If you want to, or have to, write a DIY expression evaluator, one way to do it is to proceed as follows:

Write yourself a class that takes a string as input and snips it up into a series of symbols, aka "tokens" which represent the component parts of the expression, e.g, numbers, operators, parentheses, names of functions, names of variables, etc; these tokens might themselves be records  or class instances and need to include a mechanisms for storing values associated with particular symbols (e.g. the tokens that represent numbers in the input).  This step is called "tokenisation" or "lexing". Store the resulting list of symbols in a list or similiar structure.  This class needs to implement a mechanism to retrieve the next symbol from the list (usually, this method is called something like "NextToken") and indicate whether there are any symbols left.  This class also needs a mechanism to "put back" a symbol (or, equivalently, "peek" the symbol following the current one).

Then, write yourself a s/ware machine which takes the tokenised symbols and "evaluates" the list of symbols to produce the (mathematical) result you're after.  This step is an order of magnitude or two more difficult than the tokenisation step.  There are numerous ways to do it. As I said an a comment earlier, a recursive descent parser is probably the most tractable approach if you've never done anything like this before.  There are countless examples in textbooks, but here's a link to an article about a Delphi implementation that should be understandable as an intro:

http://www8.umoncton.ca/umcm-deslierres_michel/Calcs/ParsingMathExpr-1.html

That article begins by noting that there are numerous pre-existing Delphi expression evaluators but makes the point that they are not necessarily the best place to start for someone wanting to learn how to write an evaluator/parser rather than just use one.  Instead it goes through the coding of an evaluator to implement this simple expression grammar:

expression : term | term + term | term − term

term :  factor | factor * factor | factor / factor

factor :   number | ( expression ) | + factor | − factor

(the vertical bar | denotes ‘or’)

The article has a link to a second part which shows had to add exponentiation to the evaluator - this is trickier than it might sound and involves issues of ambiguity:  e.g. how to evaluate - and what does it mean to write - an expression like

x^y^z

?  This relates to the issue of "associativity":  most operators are "left associative" which means that they bind more tightly to what's on the left of them than what's on their right.  The exponentiation operator is an example of the reverse, where the operator binds more tightly to what's on its right.

Have fun!

By the way, you used to see suggestions to implement an evaluator using the "shunting yard algorithm"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

to convert an "infix" expression where the operators are between the operands, as in 1 + 3 * 4 to RPN (reverse Polish notation), as used on older HP calculators.  The reason to do that was that RPN makes for much more efficient evaluation of an expression that the infix equivalent.  Ymmv, but personally I found that implementing the SY algorithm properly was actually trickier than learning how to write an evaluator in the expression/term/factor style.

Fwiw, RPN is the basis of the Forth programming language, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29, so you could write a Forth implementation in Delphi if you wanted!